# An increasing sequence converges if and only if has supremum and moreover its limit is the supremum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification

> **Statement**
>
> An increasing sequence converges (that is it has finite limit) if and only if has supremum and its limit is the supremum.

So I ask if the statement is true and so to prove it. On the contrary if the statement is not true I ask to give a counterexample. So could someone, help me?

Comment: Do you plan to stop editing your question?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Now I finished: there was only some grammar mistakes.

Comment: Is the proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Your title is a bit confusing. Should it not be something like: "...if and only if it has a supremum (so period). **Moreover** its limit will coincide with the supremum." The used word "and" could mean that this coincidence is a part of the condition (which is IMV not the case).

Comment: You kept writing “limited” where you should have written “bounded”.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Okay, thanks for your assistane. Now I edit the mistake you saw. However could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744383/prove-that-lf-p-inf-sum-r-in-p-fx-r-cdot-vrx-r-in-r-and-uf-p)? Pehraps I found an answer at my question but I can't say by my self if it is correct: so I'd like to know your point of view. So could you help me, please?

Comment: @drhab Okay, now I edit the title, then if you want you can edit it too.

Comment: It is okay now.

Comment: @Okay, thanks too much for your assistance! Then if you like you can see if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744383/prove-that-lf-p-inf-sum-r-in-p-fx-r-cdot-vrx-r-in-r-and-uf-p) other proof is correct. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma**

An increasing sequence converges (that is it has finite limit) if and only if has supremum and its limit is the supremum.

*Proof*. So if $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is an increasing sequence that converges (that is it has finite limit) then we prove that limit $l$ is an upper bound. So if $l$ was not an upper bound then there must exist $n_l\in\Bbb N$ such that $l<a_{n_l}$ and so for $\epsilon:=(a_{n_l}-l)$ by the convergence to $l$ of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ there exist $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $a_n<\epsilon +l=a_l$ for any $n\ge n_0$ and so by the increase of the sequence it would be $n_0<n_l$ so that finally it would be $a_{n_l}<\epsilon+l=a_{n_l}$ that obviously is impossible. So the set of the upper bound of the sequence is not empty and so by well-know property of sets of real numbers we conclude that the sequence is bounded above, that is has a supremum. Now we prove that $l$ is the minimum of the upper bound. So if $l$ is the limit of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there must exist $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $l-\epsilon<a_n$ for any $n\ge n_0$ so that by the arbitrariness of $\epsilon>0$ we conclude that $l$ is the minimum of the upper bound, that is it is the supremum.